# carouFredSel current image caption

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

I was wondering if any of you are familiar with the [carouFredSel script](http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl). I love the script but I am struggling to extract the number of the current slide, so I can show a caption.

The problem I'm having is that I show 3 slides next to each other and the script loads the caption for EACH of the slides, instead of showing only the one in the middle. I can't even figure out how to grab the current item number so that I could use it to fadeIn the correct caption...

Comment: Have you seen the "current_position()" method that's documented for that plugin?

Comment: Yeh I saw that and tried testing it by doing a simple alert, so i could see if it was detecting the right frame number. However it didn't alert anything. Not sure why, probably I'm not using it the correct way :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$("#thumbs").triggerHandler("configuration", "items.visible");` to get no of visible items. Do Math.floor() to get middle element on it.  and `$('#thumbs').trigger('slideTo', [$(this),-mid_element]);`

I managed to get something here , may its helpful to you

http://jsfiddle.net/RL8MV/12/

though its a late reply.. may be helpful someone else. :P

Answer (score 0):

To get middle element

```
// Calculate the center carousal
function getCenterThumbnail() {
var $thumbnail =  $('#thumbnail'),
    $visible = $thumbnail.triggerHandler( 'currentVisible' ),
    center = Math.floor($visible.length / 2);
  return center;
}
```

and to slide to middle

```
$('#thumbnail').trigger( 'slideTo', [ +position, -center ] );
```

**position** is current element (image) position.